# XHTML 1.0 Strict: Problems with form/ javascript

Tags: javascript, css, html

I am writing a program for class which must validate with XHTML 1.0 Strict. According to the validator at w3, my page validates. I also have an HTML5 version of this (which was the original), which validates and works the way it should.

What should happen is that:

When the "check available" button is clicked, the function "checkAvailable" should simply find which radio button was selected, find the corresponding "slot[index]" and "available[index] where the indexes match, and display whether the slot is available or not. However this is not doing anything at all either.

This is the javascript (shortened):

```
<script type = "text/javascript"><![CDATA[
var slotIndex = 0;
var slot = new Array();
    //9:00AM - 10:00AM
    slot[0] = "Monday: 9:00AM - 10:00AM";
    slot[1] = "Tuesday: 9:00AM - 10:00AM";
    slot[2] = "Wednesday: 9:00AM - 10:00AM";
    slot[3] = "Thursday: 9:00AM - 10:00AM";
    slot[4] = "Friday: 9:00AM - 10:00AM";
    slot[5] = "Saturday: 9:00AM - 10:00AM";

var available = new Array();
    //9:00AM - 10:00AM
    available[0] = false;
    available[1] = true; 
    available[2] = false;
    available[3] = true;
    available[4] = true;
    available[5] = false;

function getSlotIndex(index)
{
    slotIndex = index;
}
function checkAvailable(slot)
{
    var msg = "";
    if(available[slotIndex] == true)
    {
        msg = "Available";
        return msg;
    }
    else
    {
        msg = "Not available";
        return msg;
    }               
}
```

These are some radio buttons:

```
<tr>
<td> 9:00AM - 10:00AM<br /><input type = "radio" name = "slot" value = "0" id = "s0" onclick = "getSlotIndex(this.value)"></input></td>
<td> 9:00AM - 10:00AM<br /><input type = "radio" name = "slot" value = "1" id = "s1" onclick = "getSlotIndex(this.value)"></input></td>
<td> 9:00AM - 10:00AM<br /><input type = "radio" name = "slot" value = "2" id = "s2" onclick = "getSlotIndex(this.value)"></input></td>
<td> 9:00AM - 10:00AM<br /><input type = "radio" name = "slot" value = "3" id = "s3" onclick = "getSlotIndex(this.value)"></input></td>
<td> 9:00AM - 10:00AM<br /><input type = "radio" name = "slot" value = "4" id = "s4" onclick = "getSlotIndex(this.value)"></input></td>
<td> 9:00AM - 10:00AM<br /><input type = "radio" name = "slot" value = "5" id = "s5" onclick = "getSlotIndex(this.value)"></input></td>
<td> CLOSED </td>
</tr>
```

And here are the buttons which run the functions:

```
<input type = "button" name = "find_available" value = "Find available" onclick = "findAvailable()"></input>
<input type = "text" name = "this.form['isAvailable']" size = "25"></input>
```

Comment: I doubt this code works in any mode. Calling [`document.write()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.write) after the page has been parsed, will open a new document and wipe out _all_ the previous code on the page. Though `document.write()` doesn't work at all in XHTML...

Comment: How about the "checkAvailable" function? I know the other function is trash. I plan to come up with a better way to include a loop somewhere (this is a requirement for the assignment). But any help on the checkAvailable one and why it is not working?

Comment: Looks like `isAvailable` is not defined at the time you try to add a property to it. You've to define `isAvailable` before adding properties to it.

Comment: I put it so that it was declared before it, like so:

<input type = "text" name = "isAvailable" size = "25">
</input><input type = "button" value = "Check availability" onclick = "isAvailable.value = checkAvailable(slot)"></input> 

But it still refuses to work

Comment: Hmm... Your reference has been deprecated over ten years ago : ). Give an `id` for your input, and refer it with `document.getElementById()`. Or, if these `input`s are in a `form`, you can you use `this.form['isAvailable']`.

Comment: the inputs are in a form. I edited the last section of code on my original post. Is that where i was supposed to add "this.form['isAvailable']? It is still not working unfortunately.

Comment: Actually no, you were supposed to do this: `onclick = "this.form['isAvailable'].value = checkAvailable(slot)"`, and keep the original `name`s.

Comment: I did that but it is still not working

Comment: Umh... I don't know any more, can you provide a link to the page, I'll take a closer look at it.

Comment: I can do that, but it is not up on the web. How should i provide the webpage?

Comment: You'd need a public server... At http://jsfiddle.net you could provide a simpilied example perhaps? Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: here is the page: http://jsfiddle.net/VG9WU/3/

Comment: Are you sure that validates as HTML5? `</input>` end tags are never allowed in any version of HTML or XHTML.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to post your page in full at http://pastebin.com/. This would allow us to save your code to a local file and see what the problem with it is.

As far as the fiddle goes, your primary problem is how you set up the fiddle. By setting the menu to `onLoad`, jsFiddle wraps whatever is in the JavaScript pane in an anonymous function that runs on `window.onload` and by pasting all of your HTML markup, CSS, and JavaScript in the JavaScript pane, you get your page wrapped in an HTML5 page.

Set it up like this instead:

[image: jsFiddle setup]

Changing to `No wrap - in <head>` makes your `checkAvailable` visible to the global scope which allows your inline event handlers to see the function (and, ergo, execute it).

You can also pick `No wrap - in <body>` with no ill effects.

jsFiddle also does not allow use of `document.write` as it causes problems with the rendered output. Use of  `document.write` is, generally-speaking, a bad practice and you should avoid it when possible. There are very few specific use cases where you do want to use `document.write` and there are much better DOM insertion techniques available.

I changed the `findAvailable` function to use string concatenation on an extra `div` element that I added after the `form` element as a quick-and-hacky example:

```
function findAvailable() {
    var avail = document.getElementById('list_available_slots');
    for (i = 0; i < 83; i = i + 1) {
        if (available[i] == true) {
            avail.innerHTML += slot[i] + "<br />Available<br />";
        }
    }
}
```

Also, I had to add `background-color: black !important;` to the CSS `html, body`  definition to make your white text visible.

Here's the updated (working) fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/VG9WU/4/

Lastly, while your post make it perfectly clear that this is for a class, your code includes **several** (generally) bad practices that you will want to move away from *as you progress*. They are, in no particular order (and "not limited to" as I'm sure I didn't catch everything), as follows:

- inline JavaScript event handlers
- inline style definitions
- not utilizing self-closing tags (i.e., `<img ...></img>` instead of `<img ... />`)
- using `<br />` elements instead of using CSS to change the `display` to `block`
- not using `label` elements for your radio buttons (which makes them much easier to click)
- using `name` instead of `id` for your inputs (yes, you use `id` for your radios but your should use them for your `button`s and other inputs as well as it allows for use of `document.getElementById`)
- use of `new Array()` as opposed to `[]`
- globally-scoped variables
- separation of related data (`slot` and `available` should be defined together)
- using `<hr />` when CSS would do
- not using ECMAScript strict mode ("fail fast and fail loudly") to help find errors

Here's a functional *example* of your project written using better practices: http://jsfiddle.net/5TXDL/